# dylib image not found in OpenCV

Tags: c++, macos, opencv

I have a C++ project that I configure the CMake like:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(ubimet main.cpp data.cpp)
target_link_libraries(ubimet ${OpenCV_LIBS})
set_property(TARGET ubimet PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 17)
```

When I include the header `#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>` I get:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/protobuf/lib/libprotobuf.22.dylib
      Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_dnn.4.3.dylib
      Reason: image not found
    Abort trap: 6
```

In that folder I have:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Hector-2:lib hectoresteban$ ls
libprotobuf-lite.23.dylib   libprotobuf.23.dylib        libprotoc.23.dylib      pkgconfig
libprotobuf-lite.a      libprotobuf.a           libprotoc.a         python3.8
libprotobuf-lite.dylib      libprotobuf.dylib       libprotoc.dylib
```

Comment: Does `/usr/local/opt/protobuf/lib/libprotobuf.22.dylib` exist? How did you install opencv?

Comment: homebrew install opencv, I have added what is in the folder

Comment: Looks like protobuf has been upgraded without upgrading opencv, try reinstalling opencv

Comment: Should I delete opencv? and reinstall it?

Comment: Maybe, i seem to remember homebrew has a reinstall command too though

Comment: What is the result of this in terminal? ```pkg-config --modversion opencv```